# How to run docker containers with the command './go.sh' and ju172 as my argument

Tags: docker, command-line, containers

I am trying to run this docker container, migliava/themepark2-cli, with the command './go.sh and ju172 as an arugment.
I am unsure what to execute to accomplish this.

I have tried running this

docker run -it -ju172 migliava/themepark2-cli

and this tells me unknown shorthand flag j in -ju172

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there

```bash
$ docker run -it migliava/themepark2-cli ./go.sh ju172
```